# OpenWall BCrypt: Example of Hashing Input using crypt_r and explanation of inputs and best practice

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, cryptography, bcrypt

I am struggling with finding examples for OpenWall's bcrypt implementation that use crypt_gensalt_rn and crypt_r that also explain in depth exactly what is happening in terms of input, settings etc and more generally the cryptographic component. crypt and crypt_gensalt are not really viable due to them not being MT-Safe so I am trying to better understand the rn, ra, and r implementations.

Summary: I want to better understand what the

1. the parameters to the function are and what their purposes are.
2. What are the best practices cryptographically for password hashing using these re-entrant ones and how to use them safely in a MT environment so I am not one of those developers who just uses crypto functions without understanding the implications of them and pitfalls.
3. when generating random bytes for the salt generator, what is a cryptographically strong source for random bytes?

I am also open to recommendations to other libraries etc. but they need to be production ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to solve this on my own. Here is what I found out:

1a. crypt_gensalt_rn:

- prefix = Prefix code in the form of $<Algorithim>$ ex. $2a$
- count : The number of rounds you want the hashing algorithim to run. Set this value by response time. (ie. if you want to finish a hash in 1s, then run a benchmark and figure out the # of rounds needed to respond in 1s)
- rbytes, nrbytes : rbytes is a set of random bytes and nrbytes is the length of said char array of randombytes. You can pass NULL to rbytes and 0 to nrbytes to have the OS get them for you (best practice typically unless OS doesn't have random bytes hardware needed which can result in a security risk)
- output, output_size : This is defined by each algorithm individually. In the case of bcrypt it is 32 or the length of the setting string for crypt_ra. This stores in the format of $<Algorithim>$<rounds>$<salt> for bcrypt and many others.
  1b. crypt_ra(const char *phrase, const char *setting, void **data, int *size);
- phrase : the text you want to hash
- setting: the setting string (ie. char* output) made in crypt_gensalt_rn.
- data : a pointer to a generic crypt_struct used by most linux libraries. This is where crypt_ra will allocate a struct you need to free.
- size : A pointer to an integer that crypt_ra will set to the length in bytes of the crypt struct.

2. Ra and RN are safe in Multithreaded environments. Make sure if your server doesn't support Random Byte Generation via hardware there can be a security risk (this was reported). Set rounds to a time you want it to take to verify a password not a # of rounds.
3. You can use the OS if it has the appropriate hardware. Otherwise you can use RNG like mersenne twister.